# Download a file instead of opening in a web page

Tags: html, browser, download, href

I need to download a CSV file hosted on my Google Drive with a hyperlink.
Whenever I click the download link, I get a garbage file named as `view.html`.
What can be the reason for this unusual behavior? Demo HTML lines are:

```
<html>
<body>
<a  href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByK27OBInnBnUlJ1ZFg3WVVQbjQ" download> Demo data </a>                       
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is just the sharing link. You need to generate the direct download link separately. [It's this one.](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0ByK27OBInnBnUlJ1ZFg3WVVQbjQ)

Comment: How to generate download link of Google doc file?

Comment: Look at the url. Append the spreadsheet id to the end of the url `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=`